# Read string contents from HDFS in Scala

Tags: scala, hdfs

What is an easy way to read from HDFS in Scala, and also be able to create unit tests that rely on HDFS without having a requirement of access to that HDFS? Somehow mock/stub HDFS?

Comment: You probably know that asking a library recommendation in general is off-topic in Stack Overflow. May I suggest you do some research and come back with specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using [spark](http://spark.apache.org/).

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```